# how can I call a JS self-executing function later if I want?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a function that executes immediately but can also be later like:

```
var test = function (e){ console.log('hello'+e); }();
$('#some_element').click(function(e){
    test(' world');
});
```

where in this case, the results I would want would be:

```
helloundefined
hello world
```

I am not grasping why calling test later returns 'test is not a function'.

Comment: if you define "test" within the body of another function it is possible that the variable "test" goes out of scope.

Comment: you are storing the return value of the function into `test`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You define `test` like this:

```
var test = function (e){ console.log('hello'+e); }();
```

This creates a closure and then immediately calls it. Since there's no explicit `return` in the closure, it returns `undefined`. Now `test` contains `undefined`. Later, in the closure passed to `click`, it tries to call `test`. `test` is still `undefined`. You end up doing something like this:

```
undefined(' world');
```

You say you wanted it to output this:

```
helloundefined
hello world
```

In that case, you can do this:

```
var test = function test(e) { console.log('hello'+e); return test; }();
```

As a side effect, it also makes `test` chainable, so you could do this:

```
test(" world")(" stack overflow")(" internet");
```

And the result (excluding the first `helloundefined`) would be:

```
hello world
hello stack overflow
hello internet
```

Comment: Oooo...how nifty!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  So technically speaking (and correct me if I'm wrong), the solution is a function called 'test', it contains a return value of itself (or it's name?), has a reference value called 'test' and is executed immediately.

Comment: @Brandon: It's a little tricky, but it has a named closure called `test`. When it's called, it does its thing and then returns itself (since using its name inside it is found before the parent's `var`). Anyway, after it's defined, it's called. The call returns itself, so it can be called again.

Comment: This inspired me to go learn about closures.  This stuff at first glance looks like magick.  icktoofay, the chainable information you provided was really interesting and unlike what I expected from my knowledge of the chaining pattern.  Do you by chance have any concrete resources to suggest for reading up on making functions chainable or closures either?

Comment: @Brandon: I don't know of any resources about closures and chaining off hand, but you could probably ask another question about resources on them. If you search on Google you might find some good things as well. To be brief, chaining works by having a function either return an object (likely containing itself) or a function. Then you can call the result (or properties of it) again. Of course, chaining doesn't really work if you have to return something, since you're already returning a function/object... Anyway, a very popular library that uses chaining is jQuery. You may want to look at it.

Answer (score 4):

```
var test = function (e){ console.log('hello'+e); }();
```

Those parens at the end mean that `test` is the *result of evaluating a function call* (in other words the return value of the function), not the function itself.

Try this:

```
var testFunc = function (e){ console.log('hello'+e); };
testFunc();
$('#some_element').click(function(e){
    testFunc(' world');
});
```

Comment: Yes, that is the way I was initially had been doing things but I wanted to see how a self-executing could apply in my case.

Answer (score 3):

```
var test;
(test = function( e ) { console.log('hello'+e); } )(); //helloundefined

test( ' world' ); //hello world
```

Comment: Yet another way of writing the solution!  Strangely enough, JS doesn't even require that you write the 'var test;' line.  This is simple and elegant but I have not a clue what to say about this solution.  Meouw, how would you describe what is happening in plain English?  Also, why does this not need a return value of itself like the solution posted above?

Comment: I will try to describe what is happening in plain English. The value of an assignment in javascript (and other languages) is the value of the right most term. That's why you can chain assignment: `a = b = 10`. In this case I am using this effect by

Comment: In this case I am using this effect by enclosing the assignment in parenthesis and invoking the 'value' which happens to be a function. The function is, of course, also stored in the variable, `test` for later invocation.

Comment: Totally awesome and useful.  Thank you much meouw

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning the **return value** of the function to `test`, not the function itself. I don't think you can use the self-executing shortcut if you also want to assign it to a variable. You'll need to do:

```
var test = function (e){ console.log('hello'+e); };
test();
$('#some_element').click(function(e){
    test(' world');
});
```